# Abrir arquivos através do diretório relativo

Tags: python, arquivo, python-2.7

Como faço para ler o caminho relativo de arquivo que esteja em um diretório diferente do arquivo python e depois abrir esse arquivo?

Por exemplo:
Para o arquivo1 no diretório nome_projeto/arquivos/arquivo1.txt e o código python no diretório nome_projeto/srcfuncão `os.path.relpath` me retorna arquivo1.txt como caminho relativo e a função open gera  uma exceção de 
`IOError`.

Comment: Quer abrir um arquivo python ou ler o arquivo em outro diretório?

Comment: Ler arquivo em outro diretório

Comment: Já reli a pergunta algumas vezes e não consegui entender o que foi perguntado. Se você sabe onde está o arquivo em relação ao seu código, o que exatamente você precisa fazer? Se o seu código está em `srcfuncão`, basta abrir o arquivo `arquivos/arquivo1.txt`.

Comment: É só um exemplo. Quiz apenas dizer que o arquivo e o código estão em diretórios distintos

Comment: Como você esta tentando fazer ? Pode colocar o código ?